# How do I set the flag CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS to allow for calling multiple stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, joomla, mariadb

How do I set the flag CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS for calling multiple stored procedures in a single stored procedure?  I have 30 stored procedures I would like to execute with a button click to process user data.  It seems that creating a single procedure to execute the 30 others would be easiest but this triggers a syntax error.  Executing one stored procedure in a stored procedure works just fine, adding even one more creates an error.  My research has indicated by setting the CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS flag I can execute multiple procedures but there is little documentation on how to do this within a CMS like Joomla.  I am working with Joomla 3 / mysql 5.7 / mariadb.  Do I have to modify core code? Or is there a way to set the flag externally?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking because if it is a Joomla question you would n't be asking how to do something in phpmyadmin -- why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry - I've modified it for clarity.  Does that help?

Comment: So you want to do this from within Joomla?  It sounds like you might want to make a plug in or a module. Who would be clicking the button? In the Site or Administrator?  Are you using the Joomla query building api?

Comment: I don't necessarily want a module or plugin.  I am adding some basic html and php within an article to create a submit button and process mysql data previously entered to generate results for a user.  I'm really just trying to figure out how to execute multiple stored procedures at once.  I have the rest figured out.  If that's not possible I have some major work to do.  I've dug into the mysql_com.h file - I might be able to activate the client_multi_statements flag there but there seems to be very little step by step documentation on enable this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out how to enable CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS in Joomla.  I was able to solve my issue by using this bit of code to split my queries into an array of queries that the server will allow to process.

```
JDatabaseDriver::splitSql($query);

$query =  "CALL ...;CALL...;...;";

$queries = $db->splitSql($query);

foreach( $queries AS $sql ) 
{
$db->setQuery($sql) ->execute();
$db->query();
}
```

Cheers